# user_register_form not give pre filled form

Tags: 7

I have created a module for user listing. when I edit any user then call drupal_get_form('user_register_form', $existing_account);, its not give me form with user data.

I used Profile2 module to add some custom filed in user registration page. Now in admin , I need those custom fields with user data in it.
for that I used drupal_get_form('user_register_form', $existing_account); function where $existing_account = user_load($uid, $reset = TRUE);

```
  function mymodule_create_subscriber() {
  ....

  $existing_account = user_load($uid, $reset = TRUE);

  .......
  $extra =drupal_get_form('user_register_form', $existing_account); 

   $form = array_merge($form,$extra);

     $form[actions]['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Update Subscriber'),
      '#weight' => 30
$form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_create_subscriber_validate';
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_create_subscriber_submit';
....
}

function mymodule_create_subscriber_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

 ....some code

  return;
}

function mymodule_create_subscriber_submit(&$form, &$form_state) {
$account = array();
  $account = $form_state['values'];

......
 $account = user_save($existing_account, $account, $category);
   .....
}
```

Please help me where I am doing wrong or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hack user registration instead of extending the feature in a right way.

If your requirement is additional validations on user registration form try using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

More about hooks [here](https://drupal.org/node/292).

Comment: Thanks anil for your suggestion, but here I am using user_register_form in a custom form.....ok let me explain it.

In Admin I have user listing (custom) and when I edit any user then I can see form with username, email, password, status textboxes

I created First Name and Last Name and Profile custom fields using Profile2 module.
Custom fields are displaying i user edit form but its not pre filled mean all fields come blank....and also its give ne already existing email id when I submit the form after fill all fields.

Comment: Drupal does provide Edit User functionality out of the box .. Why are you recreating separate page for that ? Normally path for user edit is user/{uid}/edit...

Comment: :), its a different module using user listing but have more functionality in edit section. so please help me to use "user_register_form" function in my form